# Condtional XMLElement in c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to serialize to XML using the following class file

```
public class BatchFile
{
    [XmlElement("File1")]
    public List<string> FileObject { get; set; }
}
```

Following is my C# code to serialize this class

```
 var batchFile = new BatchFile();
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BatchFile));
 using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"E:\BatchFile1.xml"))
  {               
  serializer.Serialize(writer, batchFile);
  }
```

I need to use the XMLElement on FileObject property dynamically.

It will be File1 or File2 or File3.

I am not sure how to proceed on this.

Have referred 
    [How do I model a dynamic XML element in a C# serialization class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558659/how-do-i-model-a-dynamic-xml-element-in-a-c-sharp-serialization-class)
and
 [Change xml element value dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534656/change-xml-element-value-dynamically)

But they dont seem to work for me.

Comment: I'm a little confused about how you want your XML to look.  Are you saying you have a list of strings, want to represent the list as a set of identically named elements with a dynamically bound name?  Or do you want to name each list entry individually?  If you showed us some example XML it might help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - I don't believe you're using the right tool for the job. XML serialization is a tool that allows you to convert an object into an easily transported (and human-readable) form - and back. This does imply a fixed schema.

If you insist on doing it using XML serialization, why not do the simplest approach?

```
[XmlElement("File1")]
public List<string> File1 { get; set; }

[XmlElement("File2")]
public List<string> File2 { get; set; }

[XmlElement("File3")]
public List<string> File3 { get; set; }

[XmlIgnore]
public List<string> FileObject
{
   get { return this.File1 ?? this.File2 ?? this.File3; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want nodes named `File1` through `FileN` you're going to have to implement `IXmlSerializable` and build/parse the XML manually.  There are no attributes that will enumerate collection items and give then sequential names.

If you only support a finite number of elements (say 3), you could add properties for those 3 elements:

```
public class BatchFile
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<string> FileObject { get; set; }

    public string File1 
    { 
        get {return FileObject[0];} 
        set {FileObject[0] = value; }
    }

    public string File2 { get; set; }
    { 
        get {return FileObject[1];} 
        set {FileObject[1] = value; }
    }

    public string File3 { get; set; }
    { 
        get {return FileObject[2];} 
        set {FileObject[2] = value; }
    }

}
```

You'll need to add appropriate bounds checking, of course.

Comment: Shouldn't the type for the File1-3 properties be `string` instead of `List<string>`